# make element rounded if have attribute rounded

Tags: polymer

I am trying to make an element rounded based on it having a rounded attribute or not.

What I have attempted without success.

```
<polymer-element name="my-navbar" attributes="rounded">
    <template>
        <content>
        </content>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('my-navbar', {
            created: function () {
                if(this.rounded) {
                    this.style.borderRadius = '5px'
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can already be achieved with CSS:

```
<polymer-element name="my-elem" noscript>
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        background: red;
        color: white;
        padding: 8px;
        margin: 8px;
      }
      :host([rounded]) {
        border-radius: 8px;
      }
    </style>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<my-elem rounded>I'm rounded!</my-elem>

<my-elem>I'm rectangular!</my-elem>
```

See ["A Guide to Styling Elements"](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html) for more information.